# Playsound not playing the music

Tags: python

I use the `playsound` library and the code below does not work.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('Startup.mp3',True)
```

and i get this error

```
 Error 277 for command:
        open "Startup.mp3" alias playsound_0.2205048182406233
    A problem occurred in initializing MCI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into issue with that library. I would recommend you to use the `pygames` library and from it the `mixer` function.

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init() # initiate the mixer instance
mixer.music.load('money.wav') # loads the music, can be also mp3 file.
mixer.music.play() # plays the music
```

Comment: i get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):

    mixer.music.load('Startup.mp3')
pygame.error: Error reading the stream. (code 18)

Comment: hmm what else can i do

Comment: @sashank Convert `.mp3` to `.wav` and try to load the `.wav` file. The `.mp3` files support in that library is not good enough and can spawn errors.

Comment: nope i get this error `    mixer.music.load('Startup.wav')
pygame.error: Unknown WAVE format
`

Comment: @sashank have you called before the mixer.init()?

Comment: Yes i used the same code you gave , i just changed the file name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217688/discussion-between-aleksander-ikleiw-and-sashank).

Answer (score 1):

Install K-lite codec pack standard. It's work for me.
http://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_standard.htm

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.